# Semantic ui table responsive based on content

Tags: javascript, css, semantic-ui

i am using semantic ui for my website. in semantic ui is there any option to stack the table only, if when the contents of cell goes bigger else remain same on smaller devices.

Here is my sample [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/err9mrcx/)

In this i have some actions link icon in the action column. if the width of icon column is increase than the its td width(table goes out of the screen), at that point only i want the table to be stackable

```
$('#example').DataTable();
```

Comment: And the question is....? Also post the code you use

Comment: i have updated the question and added my working fiddle